# ActiveX Microsoft Web Browser Object (embedding web page into excel file)

Tags: vba, excel, webbrowser-control

I try to embed web page into .xlsm Excel 2010 file. That what I have made so far :
In Sheet1 I've inserted ActiveX control called 'Microsoft Web Browser' its default name is WebBrowser1 (Developer->Insert->More Controls->Microsoft Web Browser). Then using VBA editor I placed following code into sheet module Sheet1 :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/"
End Sub
```

I've tried various websites and html files placed on my local hard drive but the content displayed in WebBrowser1 control is always the same - 'Internet Explorer Cannot Display The Webpage' error with no error from Excel VBA alone. It seems that Microsoft Web Browser Object can't establish connection to web page.

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
    'declare the web browser object for future reference and / or for listening to its events
    Dim WithEvents ie As WebBrowser

    'navigate when the worksheet is activated.
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
        Set ie = ActiveSheet.WebBrowser1
        ie.Navigate2 "http://stackoverflow.com/"
    End Sub
```

Comment: what does declaring with ` Dim WithEvents` change for properties of `WebBrowser` object ?

Comment: @Qbik The statement Dim WithEvents let's register the object in question so VBA can listen to it's event, much like for the worksheet object that expose by default it's events (onActivate , SelectionChange , ecc.). So for the WebBrowser , for example ,  you will be able to code on the  OnQuit , onDownloadComplete events , and many more. It doesn't actually change it's property .

Answer (score -1):

After Navigate you have to put parenthesis maybe that's why it cannot read the site.
It should be like

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: This isn't true.   Either syntax is supported.